# Diferença entre tempo de execução - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

**Preciso de ajuda, sou iniciante.**

Quero pegar a diferença entre minutos e segundos entre duas colunas na mesma tabela, tentei os casos abaixo mas sem sucesso. Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` dentro do Grafana, extraindo direto de uma base de PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
   justify_hours(column_A,column_B)
FROM table
```

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(DAYS FROM (coluna_A-coluna_B)) as dias,
   EXTRACT(HOURS FROM (coluna_A-coluna_B)) as horas
FROM tabela
```

```
SELECT column_A, AGE(column_A,column_B) FROM table WHERE AGE(column_A,column_B) >='1 min'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a *function* `DATE_PART`, para pegar a parte da data que se deseja (dias, horas, etc) e a *function* `AGE` que retorna o intervalo entre datas.

Pegando o seu exemplo:

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(DAYS FROM (coluna_A-coluna_B)) as dias,
   EXTRACT(HOURS FROM (coluna_A-coluna_B)) as horas
FROM tabela
```

Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
   DATE_PART('day', AGE(coluna_A, coluna_B)) AS dias,
   DATE_PART('hour', AGE(coluna_A, coluna_B)) AS horas,
FROM tabela
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7988d/1

Documentação da funções de data do `PostgreSQL`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-datetime.html